# Help for formula for regularized logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, data-science-model

Can someone help me write the cost function for logistic regression in octave.These are the variables I used...

```
X_t = [ 1.00000   0.10000   0.60000   1.10000;
   1.00000   0.20000   0.70000   1.20000;
   1.00000   0.30000   0.80000   1.30000;
   1.00000   0.40000   0.90000   1.40000;
   1.00000   0.50000   1.00000   1.50000];

y_t = [1;0;1;0;1];
lambda_t = 3;
theta_t = [-2;-1;1;2];

cost = (-1/5)*sum((transpose(-y_t)*log(1./(1+e.^(X_t*theta_t))))+(transpose(1-y_t)*log(1-(1./(1+e.^(X_t*theta_t))))))+((lambda_t/(2*5))*sum(theta_t.*theta_t));`
```

I get a cost of approx~2.2, but the aim was to get at least 2.5 for the minimum accuracy of my model.

Can someone point out the mistake that I have done and help me, please?

Comment: So you're saying that your cost is lower than expected? Isn't that a good thing?

Comment: Hmm you are right.By the way thanks for editing.I think there is something wrong with my gradeint's value then.I came across this project to build a number recognizer for a ML project in coursera.If you don't mind spending some time going throught the files,heres the link  https://s3.amazonaws.com/spark-public/ml/exercises/on-demand/machine-learning-ex3.zip read the ex3 pdf file for further info.Could you help me with the regularized logistic regression part?(to code it in the lrCostfunction.m file)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you define a sigmoid function before so that the formula will look more simple, and the mistake I think is that when you use a vectorized version as you did you do not have to sum at the beginning, and the transpose is done this way: $y_t'$ instead of transpose($y_t$) just to make things simpler and easier.
Also, you wrote transpose($-y_t$) while it should be transposed ($y_t$) because the $ - $ sign is at the start of the formula.

$h_\theta$ = sigmoid($\theta' \cdot X$) = $\frac{1}{1+exp(-X' \cdot \theta)}$

$cost = \frac{-1}{m}  \cdot (y'*log(h_\theta)+(1-y') \cdot log(1-h_{\theta})) + (\frac{\lambda}{2m}) \cdot \sum(\theta^2)$

Comment: Do you think the  '  can work in word-pad because it gave me an error message when I tried to run my data-plotting code.